# pyqt is installed but it won't import (Mac)

Tags: python, import, pyqt4

I installed PyQt4 and I have xcode, Qt, Sip, and Python 2.7. When I check in terminal, it says that PyQt is installed and when I view the path there is no PyQt in the path. I have put it in the path before but it goes away when I close the shell. When I try and import it it says no module named PyQt4. Help

```
brew install pyqt
Warning: pyqt-4.11.4 already installed


>>> for f in sys.path:
print f
/Users/lucygrant/Documents
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages



>>> import PyQt4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyQt4
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that adding PyQt4 to PATH solved your problem before, do it again except now do it in the ~/.bashrc file. So, as follows:

1. Add PyQt4 to PATH in ~/.bashrc as you have previously done.
2. `source ~/.bashrc` from command line.
3. Reattempt import